# no matching function for call to 'make_shared'

Tags: c++11, make-shared

I am getting compiler error "no matching function for call to 'make_shared'" whenever I try to use a constructor that takes any arguments.  So, for example:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> foo = std::make_shared<int> ();
```

works fine.  But,

```
std::shared_ptr<int> foo = std::make_shared<int> (10);
```

Gives the following error:

```
/usr/bin/clang  -g -Wall -Wextra -Wc++11-extensions -c ./test.cpp
./test.cpp:7:30: error: no matching function for call to 'make_shared'
  std::shared_ptr<int> foo = std::make_shared<int> (10);
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4700:1: note: candidate function [with _Tp = int, _A0 = int]
  not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
make_shared(_A0& __a0)
```

I took the above code directly from here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/make_shared/
and that code runs fine on cpp.sh web site.  I suspect that there is something wrong with my compiler set up.  Running in iTerm on a macbook.  Also, I get the same error even if I remove the various options to clang shown above.  Any ideas?  Is it possible that my header file for  needs to be updated?  It's from Sep 4 2015.  Seems recent enough for C++11 to work.

```
$ /usr/bin/clang --version
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix

$ ls -l /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  174919 Sep  4  2015 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory
```

Comment: What version of Clang do you have? This [should not be a requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) of `make_shared`.

Comment: #include <memory>?

Comment: $ /usr/bin/clang --version
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: YES, #include <memory> ... code was tested exactly as it appears here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/make_shared/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is complaining you using an prvalue `10`. Try to use

```
int avar = 10;
auto foo = std::make_shared<int> (avar);
```

It is interesting to see what happens when using a lvalue.

Did you build the std library locally? If you are, maybe you could try to rebuild again or grab a prebuilt library from somewhere.

I tested the code on https://godbolt.org/ with configuration `x86-64 clang 7.0.0` and `-std=c++11`. it works fine. Even you using iOS, it should be good on that os I guess.

I also see you using `-Wc++11-extensions` when you building. Try use `-std=c++11` instead maybe?

---

Edit by [DG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639359/daniel-goldfarb):  As noted in my comment below, this last suggestion, "**Try use `-std=c++11`," worked!**  **With `-std=c++11`** then ***all*** values (lvalues, rvalues, prvalues, etc.) work fine.  See comments below.

Comment: I should have added to the question that I tried using an rvalue before.  It works.  But I shouldn't have to use a an rvalue there.  However, at the end you hit the nail on the head!   '-std=c++11' did the trick!!  Thanks.

Comment: It did a google search, maybe it is incorrect, but `-Wc++11-extensions` seems to be valid and is for a very old version of clang. My guess is in that version, maybe the rvalue reference constructor was not implemented by some reasons at that time.